# Use regular expressions to add new class to element using search/replace

Tags: html, .net, regex

I want to add a NewClass value to the class attribute and modify the text of the span using find/replace functionality with a pair of regular expressions.

```
<div>
   <span class='customer' id='phone$0'>Home</span>
<br/>
   <span class='customer' id='phone$1'>Business</span>
<br/>
   <span class='customer' id='phone$2'>Mobile</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the following result using after search/replace:

```
<span class='customer NewClass' id='phone$1'>Organization</span>
```

Also curious to know if a single find/replace operation can been used for both tasks?

Comment: do you want transform those 3 lines into 1 line?

Comment: No, just want to modify the span with id "phone1$"

Comment: Is it PHP you are coding with? Please post the full HTML sample.

Comment: I am looking for .NET Regex dialect. What I posted is the full HTML sample

Comment: I am still sure you can use HtmlAgilityPack to manipulate HTML in .NET. Are you coding in C# or VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex can do this, but be aware the using regex to change HTML can have a lot of edge cases that you may not have accounted for.

[This regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/bJ3sP0/1) shows those three `<span>` elements changed to add `NewClass` and the contents to be changed to `Organization`.

Other technologies, however, would be safer. jQuery, for example, could replace them regardless of the order of the attributes:

```
$("span#phone$1").addClass("NewClass");
$("span#phone$1").text("Organization");
```

So just be careful with it, and you should be fine.

**EDIT**

According to comments on the OP, you want to only change the span containing ID `phone$1`, so the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bJ3sP0/2) link has been updated to reflect this.

**EDIT 2**

Permalink was too long to fit into a comment, so adding [the permalink](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3cspan+class%3d%27customer)(%27+id%3d%27phone%5c%241%5b%5e%3e%5d*%3e)(%5b%5e%3c%5d%2b)&i=GIVEN%3a%0d%0a%3cdiv%3e%0d%0a+++%3cspan+class%3d%27customer%27+id%3d%27phone%240%27%3eHome%3c%2fspan%3e%0d%0a%3cbr%2f%3e%0d%0a+++%3cspan+class%3d%27customer%27+id%3d%27phone%241%27%3eBusiness%3c%2fspan%3e%0d%0a%3cbr%2f%3e%0d%0a+++%3cspan+class%3d%27customer%27+id%3d%27phone%242%27%3eMobile%3c%2fspan%3e%0d%0a%3c%2fdiv%3e%0d%0a%0d%0aDESIRED%3a%0d%0a%3cspan+class%3d%27customer+NewClass%27+id%3d%27phone%241%27%3eOrganization%3c%2fspan%3e%0d%0a&r=%241+NewClass%242Organization) here. Click on the "Content" tab at the bottom to see the replacement.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm trying to use the code on http://regexstorm.net/tester but it isn't working. I need it in .NET Regex dialect.

Comment: Edited post and added a permalink to regexstorm.net that shows the same inputs and regex working like on the regex101.com page.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I will mark as answer. Could a single find/replace operation have been used for both tasks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
'.*?' id='phone\$1'>.*?<
```

With substitution string:

```
'customer' id='phone\$1'>Organization<
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/mL2zD9/1)**

Php code

```
$re = "/'.*?' id='phone\\$1'>.*?</"; 
$str = "<div>\n   <span class='customer' id='phone\$0'>Home</span>\n<br/>\n   <span class='customer' id='phone\$1'>Business</span>\n<br/>\n   <span class='customer' id='phone\$2'>Mobile</span>\n</div>"; 
$subst = "'customerNewClass' id='phone\$1'>Organization<"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Result

```
<div>
   <span class='customer' id='phone$0'>Home</span>
<br/>
   <span class='customerNewClass' id='phone$1'>Organization</span>
<br/>
   <span class='customer' id='phone$2'>Mobile</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your tags include `preg_match` and `preg_replace`, I think you are using PHP.

Regex is generally not a good idea to manipulate HTML or XML. See [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags* SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3832970).

In PHP, you can use DOMDocument and DOMXPath with `//span[@id="phone$1"]` xpath (*get all `span` tags with `id` attribute vlaue equal to `phone$1`*):

```
$html =<<<DATA
<div>
   <span class='customer' id='phone$0'>Home</span>
<br/>
   <span class='customer' id='phone$1'>Business</span>
<br/>
   <span class='customer' id='phone$2'>Mobile</span>
</div>
DATA;
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$sps = $xp->query('//span[@id="phone$1"]');
foreach ($sps as $sp) {
    $sp->setAttribute('class', $sp->getAttribute('class') . ' NewClass');
    $sp->nodeValue = 'Organization';
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/sVoyj8)

Result:

```
<div>
   <span class="customer" id="phone$0">Home</span>
<br>
   <span class="customer NewClass" id="phone$1">Organization</span>
<br>
   <span class="customer" id="phone$2">Mobile</span>
</div>
```